# Mean-cVaR model: How can one include transaction cost

Tags: portfolio-management, portfolio-optimization, markowitz, cvar

$$
\min \delta CVaR  -  (1-\delta) \sum_i^{n} \mu_i x_i \\
\sum x_i = \sum x^{old}_i   \\
Losses(s) = \sum x_i - \sum_i^{n} (R(s,i))x_i  \\
VaRDev(s) = Losses(s) - VaR \\
CVaR  = VaR + \frac{\sum_s^{} p_s VaRDev(s)}{1-\alpha}
$$

The Markowitz style Mean-cVaR portfolio is stated above. It Appears in ***Practical financial optimization*** by Zenios. $x^{old}$ is exciting portfolio and now you want to optimize and create a new portfolio $x$. $s$ is the different scenarios.

But what if transaction costs existing so you should pay $c_{variable}$ % of how much you trade an asset and each trade have a minimum cost as well. **How can we add transaction cost to this model?**

Comment: I assume that people who knows this model can figure out what the variables stands for. Otherwise please let me know if there anything I need to clarify.

Comment: If you know how to include transaction costs in a mean variance optimization, then it's trivial to add it to a mean-cvar one.

Comment: You could write the weights $x_i= x^{old}_i+u_i-v_i$ where u represents purchases and v represents sales (with both u and v constrained to be >=0). Now the transaction cost can be written as $cu_i+cv_i$.